# Mesos : Unreserve slaves resources

Tags: mesos, marathon

Is there any way to reset all slaves reserved resources in Mesos, without configuring one by one the /unreserve http endpoint?

In Mesos documentation :

**/unreserve (since 0.25.0)**

**Suppose we want to unreserve the resources that we dynamically reserved above. We can send an HTTP POST request to the master’s /unreserve endpoint like so:**

```
$ curl -i \
  -u <operator_principal>:<password> \
  -d slaveId=<slave_id> \
  -d resources='[
    {
      "name": "cpus",
      "type": "SCALAR",
      "scalar": { "value": 8 },
      "role": "ads",
      "reservation": {
        "principal": <reserver_principal>
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "mem",
      "type": "SCALAR",
      "scalar": { "value": 4096 },
      "role": "ads",
      "reservation": {
        "principal": <reserver_principal>
      }
    }
  ]' \
  -X POST http://<ip>:<port>/master/unreserve
```

Answer (score 1):

Mesos doesn't directly provide any support for unreserving resources at more than one slave using a single operation. However, you can write a script that uses the `/unreserve` endpoint to unreserves the resources at all the slaves in the cluster, e.g., by fetching the list of slaves and reserved resources from the `/slaves` endpoint on the master (see the `reserved_resources_full` key).